# Adding a Caption to a Non-float Environment

Tags: tables, captions

I am attempting to add a caption to a non-float environment.

The following is a MWE of how I'm trying to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
     hello & world
\captionof{table}{my table}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `\captionof` command must go *outside* the `tabular` environment. You may put `tabular` plus `\captionof` inside a `minipage` environment to avoid a page break between the table and its caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
     hello & world
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{my table}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```