# TiKzpicture wont move into enumeration

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, enumerate

Just started learning TeX and got a small project to work on. 
I'm using the `varcompactitem` enviroment to enumerate a few lines and want to make sure there's a `tikzpicture` inside the first or at least between the first and second item. Code until that point looks like this:

```
\documentclass{exercise}
\lstdefinestyle{numbers}
    {numbers=left, stepnumber=1, numberstyle=\emph, numbersep=10pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\setgroup{CS2450-Werkzeuge\\Malte Schmitz, ISP}
\settitle[Übungszettel]{\texttt{LaTeX}}
\addstudent{Wintersemester 17/18}
\addstudent{11. Oktober 2017}


\lstset{language=Java,
        extendedchars=false,
        morekeywords={task,setgroup, settitle, addstudent, qed,
        subsection,settitle,taskcommand,setdefaultitem,setdefaultenum,
        setdefaultleftmargin,qedsymbol,enquote,glqq,glq,grq,grqq,lstset,
        color,lstinputlisting,lstinline,showrowcolors,hiderowcolors,
        headerrow,tick,R,N,Z,Q,set,blitz,inhead,paragraph,dx,dt,
        trans,zz,DeclareMathOperator,operatorname,op}}

\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Aufgabe}
Sie haben dieses mit der Schreibmaschine und teilweise von Hand gesetzte
Dokument erhalten, über das auch schon der ein oder andere Kaffee
gelaufen ist. Leider hat niemand mehr das Original.\footnote{Tatsächlich wurde auch dieses Dokument inklusive der Kaffeeflecken und handschriftlichen Skizzen mit LaTeX gesetzt.}
Deswegen ist es jetzt Ihre Aufgabe, das Dokument mit LaTeX und TikZ neu zu setzen und
eine dazu passende Präsentation mit Beamer zu setzen.

Bearbeiten Sie diese Aufgabe in Zweiergruppen. \underline{Ein} Student der
Zweiergruppe lädt im Moodle ein Zip-Archiv hoch, das \underline{ausschließlich}
die Dateien document.tex, literature.bib, presentation.tex und
studenten.txt enthält. Die Datei studenten.txt enthält die Namen und
Matrikelnummern beider Studenten der Zweiergruppe. Die TeX-Dateien
müssen mit folgendem Aufruf unter TeX Live 2017 fehlerfrei übersetzt
werden können:

latexmk -pdf document.tex\\
latexmk -pdf presentation.tex

\subsection{Dokument}
Setzen Sie dieses Dokument mit LaTeX neu. Berücksichtigen Sie dabei die
Grundlagen guter typografischer Gestaltung und reproduzieren Sie \underline{alle
Inhalte und Strukturen} dieses Dokumentes, inklusive dieser
Aufgabenstellung.

\subsubsection{Hinweise}
\begin{varcompactitem}
    \item Setzen Sie Tabellen, Listen und Gliederungselemente mit den
            entsprechenden LaTeX-Befehlen.
\begin{figure}[h]   
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, fill=magenta!10, 
                        draw=magenta},
            op/.style={rectangle, fill=orange!10, draw=orange},
            cn/.style={diamond, aspect=2, inner sep=2pt, fill=red!10, draw=red},
            node distance=5mm]

            % Knoten
            \node[io] (techdev) {technical device};
            \node[cn, below= 1cm of techdev] (move) {Does it move?};
            \node[cn, below right= 1cm of move] (should1) {Should it?};
            \node[cn, below left= 1cm of move] (should2) {Should it?};
            \node[op, below right= 1cm of should1] (duct) {duct tape};
            \node[op, below left= 1cm of should2] (WD) {WD-40};
            \node[op, below= 1.75cm of move] (OK) {OK};

            \path[->]
                (techdev) edge (move);

            \draw[->] (move) -- node[above] {yes} ++(2,0) -| (should1);
            \draw[->] (move) -- node[above] {no} ++(-2,0) -| (should2);
            \draw[->] (should1) -- node[above] {no} ++(2,0) -| (duct);
            \draw[->] (should1) -- node[above] {yes} ++(-1.5,0) -| (OK);
            \draw[->] (should2) -- node[above] {yes} ++(-2,0) -| (WD);
            \draw[->] (should2) -- node[above] {no} ++(1.5,0) -| (OK);              
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ablaufdiagramm der Ingenieurwissenschaft}
\end{figure}        
    \item Setzen Sie die Formeln mit dem Mathematikmodus von LaTeX neu. Verwenden
            Sie Theorem-Umgebungen, um Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und Beweise
            zu setzen.
    \item Setzen Sie Grafiken mit TikZ neu. Verwenden Sie Farbe, um semantisch
            unterschiedliche Elemente sinnvoll zu kennzeichnen.
    \item Verwenden Sie LaTeX, um Gliederungselemente und Beschriftungen
            automatisch zu nummerieren.
    \item Verwenden Sie BibTeX oder BibLaTeX, um das Literaturverzeichnis zu
            setzen.
\end{varcompactitem}
```

I'm sure the picture isnt perfectly designed, but I want it between the first and second item and don't know hoe to properly align it.
Currently looks like that:
[image: Not the order I want]
I tried splitting up the enumeration already, didn't work.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is `exercise.cls`? Try to put `\end{varcompactitem}` before the figure and continue with `\begin{varcompactitem}` after the figure.

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment. Latex decides its position, even with `h` option. You should include your schema with the `tikzpicture` alone.

Comment: If you also want a caption, look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/adding-a-caption-to-a-non-float-environment

Comment: it seems that your `tikz` picture is to big that can be placed between the first and the second item.

Comment: Off topic: You should use `\LaTeX{}` for "LaTeX", `\TeX{}` for "TeX", `Ti\emph{k}Z` for TikZ.