# Subfigure caption for a non-float figure

Tags: floats, subcaption

Following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/170739) (or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/adding-a-caption-to-a-non-float-environment)), I have an inline figure with four subfigures. I would like to add subcaptions for those, preferably with automatic labels, but since the figure isn't a float, things like `\subcaptionbox` do not work. I also couldn't find a way of faking it using `\captionof`.
Does anyone know of a solution, or at least a hack to manually specify the labels and subcaptions?

```
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{image.png}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{image.png}
    }
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{image.png}
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{image.png}
    }
    \captionof{figure}{Main caption}\label{fig:some-figure}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `\captionsetup{type=figure}` or `\setcaptiontype{figure}`:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \setcaptiontype{figure}%
    \subcaptionbox{..}{..}
    \subcaptionbox{..}{..}
    \caption{Main caption}\label{fig:some-figure}
\end{minipage}
```

This is the preferred way anyway since `\captionof` could cause wrong `hyperref` jump targets.

For more information take a look at the `caption` package documentation.