# Error caption outside float when trying to caption a table

Tags: tables, errors, captions

I am trying to produce a caption to describe a table in LaTeX, however am getting an error: ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.
The formulation of the table is:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{c| c c c} 
 Campus & Main & Jubilee & Kings Meadow \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
 Main         & 0 & 21.8 & 24.6 \\
 Jubilee      & 21.8 & 0 & 9.3 \\
 Kings Meadow & 24.6 & 9.3 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table Description}
\end{center}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can not use the `\caption` command outside of a `table` or `figure` environment.

Comment: Do you want your table to float? If so, surround `tabular` and `\caption` with a `table` environment (and replace the `center` environment with the `\centering` command).

Comment: captions are for tables or figures, not tabular or center environment. Here, you should enclosed your whole code with \begin{table} and \end{table}.

Comment: Thankyou for all the help, the table environment with the \centering command was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Could i ask what it means for a table to float? And to what the difference between tabular and table is

Comment: @sam: Latex automatically places floats depending on how much space is left on a page. Floats are typically placed at the very top or the very botom of a page or at a page on their own. When using  the `table` environment, you can add a caption to a `tabular` but the table will not necessarily show up exactly where you specified it in your code.

Comment: @sam: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214840/general-differences-between-array-table-tabular-tabularx-longtable-supertab

Comment: You can influence the position of a float (see here: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)) If you prefer images and tabulars to not float but nevertheless want to add a caption, see here: [Adding a Caption to a Non-float Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45073/134144)

Comment: It behooves me to mention `\captionof` from the caption or capt-of packages.  If I had designed LaTeX, I would have combined `figure` and `table` into `float` and used `\captionof` for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principially you have two possibilities to add captions to a table (same works for figures too with `figure` instead `table`):

1. You can use a non floating table (that means you do **not** use environment `table`, which makes the table floating) as shown in the first example of the following MWE, nearly the same you used in your code. Then you need to use command `\captionof{table}{}` to get a table caption for your table outside a float (you see the relevance to the error message you got?).
2. You can use a floating table with environment `table`. That means LaTeX is allowed to place the table inside the document at a place at its own. Usually that means the table is placed at the top of the page (as done in my MWE) or at the top of the next page ... 
   Then you need to use command `\caption{}` to get a table caption ...

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\usepackage{booktabs} % <================================= better tables
\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy text 


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\centering % <====================================== to center the table
\begin{tabular}{c| c c c} 
Campus & Main & Jubilee & Kings Meadow \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
Main         & 0 & 21.8 & 24.6 \\
Jubilee      & 21.8 & 0 & 9.3 \\
Kings Meadow & 24.6 & 9.3 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table Description} % <================== from package `caption`
\label{tab:campus} % <============================== to be referenacable
\end{minipage}

\blindtext

\begin{table}%[ht] % <====================================== let table float!
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c} 
\toprule % <====================================== from package booktabs
Campus       & Main & Jubilee & Kings Meadow \\ [0.5ex] 
\midrule % <====================================== from package booktabs
Main         & 0    & 21.8    & 24.6 \\
Jubilee      & 21.8 & 0       & 9.3 \\
Kings Meadow & 24.6 & 9.3     & 0 \\
\bottomrule % <=================================== from package booktabs
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table Description a}
\label{tab:campusa}
\end{table}

Now we can reference table~\ref{tab:campus} and table~\ref{tab:campusa}.

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see table two is floating at the top of the page, has a caption and is referencable as you can see in the last sentence. You can also see that I used package `booktabs` for better horizontal lines and I deleted the vertical line (try to do not use them!) in the second table.

If you do not want the table to float at the top of the same page you can try to use option `[ht]` for `table` environment:

```
 \begin{table}[ht] % <====================================== let table float!
```

If you remove the `%` before `[ht]` in the MWE above you get the changed result:

[image: resulting pdf 2]

BTW: Have you considered to write the numberes aligned to the dezimal point? Numbers in tables looks better then IMHO. See package `dcolumn` or `siunitx` ...