How to prevent lost float error in table, in poster environment?
I understand there are a lot of "Float lost" questions already.  However, I seem to be unable to figure this one out on my own.
I'm using a template from overleaf for a poster, and I'm not able to understand why I'm told that float (the table) is lost.  Especially since I properly created the tabular environment, to the best of my knowledge.
The entire MWE is shown below.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1in,innermargin=-4.5in,blockverticalspace=-0.25in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in,paperheight=32.5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{uomtheme}

\usepackage{mwe} % for placeholder images

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{caption}
% \captionsetup[tabular]{position=bottom} %% or below

% set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{UoMTheme}
\usecolorstyle{UoMStyle}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{my title}
\author{my name}
\institute{my school}
% begin document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.32}
    \block{First section}{
Some text.
\vspace{1em}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Webb's_First_Deep_Field.jpg}
  \caption{space}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\vspace{1em}
\centering
\caption{Two tables}
\label{tab:example_1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{table1}\\
\toprule
t & $p_i$  & $o_i$ & $g_i$\\ \midrule
0 & 0.0  & $\infty $  & 4.0 \\
1 & 1.4& 25   & 1.0  \\
2 & 35& 375   & 1.0  \\
N & 00& $\infty $  & 5.0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{table2}\\
\toprule
i & 20 & 21 & 22 & N \\ \midrule
0 & 0 & 14 & 53 & 0 \\
9 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1   \\
90 & 33 & 2 & 0 & 3   \\
N & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}


\begin{table}[] means "do not place it here, at the top of the page, at the bottom of the page, or on a page by itself."  \begin{table} means "use the default values."

Thanks!  I'll try using \begin{table}.  Although I have to say I wonder: why does \begin{table}[] work on my local machine?

At a more fundamental level, float means LaTeX can put the item where LaTeX thinks is best for the table or figure.  This makes sense for a several page document.  It doesn't really make sense for a poster.  It would be better to use the caption package and not use the table environment at all.

Interesting point @Teepeemm.  Is there an example you can cite that uses the caption package for this purpose?  Thanks.

@JohnKormylo, I tried removing [].  Nothing changes.

For what it's worth, when I try to insert figures almost the exact same way, they also don't appear at all.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/adding-a-caption-to-a-non-float-environment is an example (note that you don't need the minipage environment in a poster).

"Thanks! I'll try using \begin{table}. Although I have to say I wonder: why does \begin{table}[] work on my local machine?  don't ignore warnings! latex would have warned that [] is unusable and changed it to use the default placement.  (this however is unrelated to your question as you should not be using floats at all here)

@Marijn I don't understand how that is supposed to help me.  I'd like to know how to get the table to show up in the first place - then I can start worrying about captions, etc.

@underdog987 Get rid of the table environment, and just use the stuff that was inside the environment.  The table environment does things: 1. allows the table to move elsewhere, which you don't want, and 2. allows you to have a caption.

So, you're saying I can just delete \begin{table}, and \end{table}?

By deleting \begin{table} and \end{table}, the table does indeed appear in the compiled file.  Thanks!!
I assume same goes for the figure environment?  Since it's also a float?

However, when I try to apply this solution to getting figures to cooperate, it doesn't seem to work.  I updated my question with an example.  You'll notice that the figure appears, but it doesn't appear below the text, as I would have expected.
Ideally, I'd like the figure to appear next to the table.  Or, it would be nice to at least control where the figure is.  Any ideas on how to do that?

To answer the original question: in a poster usually you don't want tables and figures to float, because then you don't have fine-grained control of where the figure appears - or it may even be lost if LaTeX doesn't find a good place to put them.
The solution is easy: remove \begin{figure} and \end{figure} around figures and \begin{table} and \end{table} around tables, leaving only the \includegraphics command for figures and \begin{tabular} and \end{tabular} (or tabularx, or tabulary, or tblr etc) for tables. This will insert the figure or the table exactly at the place in the document where you put them in the source code.
This has some disadvantages: if the figure or table doesn't fit then it will overflow, the spacing around it may be wrong, and you cannot put captions (i.e., all the things that the floating environments \begin{figure} and \begin{table} normally take care of automatically do no longer work).
For the caption you can use the caption package that provides a command \captionof{type of float}{text of the caption} that can be used at any point, before or after the figure or table (or at any other random place in the text). Sidenote: on a poster you don't necessarily need numbered, typed captions (like 'Table 1: abc'), you can just type the text of the caption in which case you don't need \captionof. You are standing next to the poster to explain and point to figures and tables yourself if needed.
For more control on the positioning it is usually the easiest to use minipages. These are environments with a specified width that act as a small 'page' on their own and can be put side by side. Within the 'page' you can center contents (such as captions). Note that within the minipage the meaning of \textwidth changes to the width of the minipage, so if you want an image to span the width of the minipage then you would use 1.0\textwidth as the width, or 0.9\textwidth (or 0.95 or so) to be on the safe side.
Make sure that there are nu empty lines or any other spacing commands like \vspace between two consecutive minipages, otherwise they will not be side by side but below eachother.
MWE (note that I didn't have the UoM themes/styles/colors, but probably this also applies with that style):
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1in,innermargin=-4in,blockverticalspace=-0.25in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in,paperheight=32.5in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{uomtheme}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
% \captionsetup[tabular]{position=bottom} %% or below

% set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
%\usetheme{UoMTheme}
%\usecolorstyle{UoMStyle}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{my title}
\author{my name}
\institute{my school}
% begin document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.32}
    \block{First section}{
Some text.

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{space}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Two tables}
\label{tab:example_1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{table1}\\
\toprule
t & $p_i$  & $o_i$ & $g_i$\\ \midrule
0 & 0.0  & $\infty $  & 4.0 \\
1 & 1.4& 25   & 1.0  \\
2 & 35& 375   & 1.0  \\
N & 00& $\infty $  & 5.0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{table2}\\
\toprule
i & 20 & 21 & 22 & N \\ \midrule
0 & 0 & 14 & 53 & 0 \\
9 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1   \\
90 & 33 & 2 & 0 & 3   \\
N & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}

Result:


Perfect answer.
